# How to use raw_input with no input

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, raw-input

I want to use `raw_input()` function in Python.
I want to receive a number from user about the size of the storage
i wrote this down :

```
number=raw_input()
```

if the user doesn't provide an input then `number = 10` so

```
if number is None:
   number = 10
```

when i print number, i get nothing i even tried:

```
if number==-1:
   number=10
print"the storage size was set to:",number
```

The output was:

> > >
> >     the storage size was set to -1

and not `10`

So how should I solve this ?

Comment: What python version are you using? Also, `number` will always be a `string`.

Comment: `raw_input()` returns a string and you are checking equality with an integer. The condition will always return false. In first case if you do not input anything, it will be just blank string( `''`)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care to distinguish between "no input" and "invalid input" (like a non-integer literal), set the default, then attempt to replace it with the user input.

```
number = 10
try:
    number = int(raw_input())
except (EOFError, ValueError):
    pass
```

`ValueError` will be raised on invalid inputs, including the empty string. `EOFError` is raised if the user does something like type Control-d in a terminal that interprets that as closing standard input.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to convert the input (default for raw_input is a string) into an int using `int()` function. But be sure that you first check if user typed something. Otherwise you can't convert an empty string. For example:

```
num_input = raw_input()
if num_input:
    number = int(num_input)
```

Then already the second part of your question should work:

```
if number == -1:
    number = 10
print "the storage size was set to:", number
```

---

The second point is that an empty `string` is not equal to `None`. `None` is the only value of `NoneType` and `""` is a `string`.

So you can compare the input with an empty string, but you can do better (an empty string is evaluated as `False`):

```
if not num_input:
    number = 10
```

and to be even more efficient you can simply add an `else` statement to my first piece of code:

```
num_input = raw_input()
if num_input:
    number = int(num_input)
else:
    number = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

compare number with empty string; not with `None` .

```
if number == '':  
    number = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python when the variable is empty then it's have inside empty **''**,
so if you want to check if your variable is unset you need to compare it to **''** and not to **None**.

```
if number=='':
   number=10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just compare number and empty.:

```
if number=="":
    number==10
```